# How can I connect multiple explorable regions into one large map?

Tags: java, 2d, architecture, game-mechanics, maps

I am planning a 2-D science fiction game involving spaceships. A major thing that I am having trouble figuring out is how to create a 2-d array of smaller maps that the player can explore.

My inspiration is the Flash game *Starfighter: Disputed Galaxy*:

[image: Map example]

The map here is composed of a 2-D array containing smaller maps called *sectors*.  Each sector is connected to surrounding sectors, such that when the player moves to the edge of a sector, they go to the next.

For example, if I was in sector `[05][01]` and I move up until I cross the edge, I am taken to sector `[06][01]`, then I go to the right, crossing the right edge of the sector, I am now taken to sector `[06][02]`.

However, if I am at a sector like `[0][5]` and attempt to go down, It will not allow me to cross the edge line of the sector. In other words, a huge map made out of smaller maps.

I'd like to know how to implement those transitions. How do I programmatically determine which sector to move to (or not allow movement) when crossing over a boundary?

Comment: Create a `MapRegion` class. Use it to hold an Array of `Tile` class instances. This way you can do `GameInstance.getInstance().getRegions(i).getProvince(p);` This way you can check to ensure i and p are in bounds before moving to them and if they're not you can [not] do something.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a seamlessly looping 2D multiplayer level?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/80385/creating-a-seamlessly-looping-2d-multiplayer-level) - the situation is different but the solution may be the same; for seamless looping levels, it is simply creating a large map by connecting a smaller map with itself, end to end.